# Deep Copy - Objects with vectors

Tags: python, deep-copy

I just typed the code bellow. I expected John to be a memeber of team_B only. When I run the code, John is beeing added to both teams, even when I use "deepcopy":

```
import copy

class team:
    players = []

team_A = team()

team_A.players.append("Tom")
team_A.players.append("Peter")
team_A.players.append("Mario")

team_B = copy.deepcopy(team_A)
team_B.players.append("John")
```

Could anyone explain this and help me fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Currently `players` is a class variable that is shared between **all** team objects, you want each instance to have it's own list of players.

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self):
        self.players = []
```

the `__init__` code is run on object construction, note the `self` keyword, this refers to this current instance of a Team.